# How to get the "status" response and passing it to hide the button from following json response?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, socket.io, uibutton

I want to hide a uibutton according to my json response "status". Please elaborate me (I'm a beginner developer). 
Following is json response getting from xcode console.

```
JSON: {
customerstatus =     {
    1 =         {
        bookingid = 469;
        status = 1;
    };
};
```

Following is my code to get the above response.

```
    -(void)SendtoGetMaterialStatus
{
    PMDReachabilityWrapper *reachability = [PMDReachabilityWrapper sharedInstance];

    if ([reachability isNetworkAvailable])
    {   NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSDictionary *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"service"];
        NSLog(@"Checkingfast%@", savedValue);
        NSDictionary *temp = @{
                               @"ent_sess_token":flStrForStr([ud objectForKey:iServeCheckUserSessionToken]),
                               @"ent_dev_id":flStrForStr([Utilities getDeviceId]),
                               @"customerid":savedValue
                               //send the customer id  from userdefault
                               };

        NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:temp];
        NSLog(@"Checking User Default Customer ID%@",temp);

        [[WebServiceHandler sharedInstance] sendRequestTypeGetReportMaterialStatus:params andDelegate:self];
        NSLog(@"Customer ID sent to Recieve the Material Status%@", params);

    }
    else
    {
        [[ProgressIndicator sharedInstance]hideProgressIndicator];
        [UIHelper showMessage:iServeNetworkErrormessage withTitle:LS(@"oops!")delegate:self];
        NSLog(@"customer ID didn't send!.");
    }

    //  [self makePostRequest:RequestTypeGetReportMaterialStatus path:kRequestTypeGetReportMaterialStatus params:params delegate:delegate];
}
```

I want to take the "status" value from the JSON and make the button hide when status = 2 or 3 otherwise keep it visible (when status = 1).

I'm passing the response according to following method. Please give me code snippet according to my code. Thanks.

```
    -(void)didFinishLoadingRequest:(RequestType)requestType withResponse:(id)response error:(NSError *)error
{
   switch (errFlag) {
    case 1:
    {
        [[ProgressIndicator sharedInstance]hideProgressIndicator];

        if (errNum == 7 || errNum == 6 || errNum == 78 || errNum == 83)//Session Expired
        {
            [[Logout sharedInstance] deleteUserSavedData:response[@"errMsg"]];
        }
        else
        {
         [UIHelper showMessage:response[@"errMsg"] withTitle:LS(@"Message")delegate:self];
        }
    }
        break;

    case 0:

    {
        if(requestType == RequestTypeGetReportMaterialStatus)
         {
            // Passing response and hiding the button
          //  ...........(help me!)
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give json with json format? And how can i get your button inside `didFinishLoadingRequest ` method?

Comment: @trungduc This is the JSON format..    {  
   "errFlag":0,
   "errMsg":"",
   "customerstatus":{  
      "1":{  
         "status":"1",
         "bookingid":"518"
      },
      "2":{  
         "status":"2",
         "bookingid":"559"
      }
   }

Comment: How can i get the button?

Comment: Seem like you don't have only one button. Right? To give you code snippet, I need you give me the way to get buttons :)

Comment: Yes I have two buttons.. And I don't have an idea to place the button hidden part.

Comment: if ([materialStringStatus isEqual:@"1"]) {
                     self.acceptButton.hidden = NO;
                     self.rejectButton.hidden = NO;
                 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below.

```
NSArray* customerstatus = response[@"customerstatus"][@"1"];
NSInteger fisrtStatus = [customerstatus[0][@"status"] integerValue];
NSInteger secondStatus = [customerstatus[1][@"status"] integerValue];

if (fisrtStatus == 1) {
  // Show your buttons
} else {
  // Hide your buttons
}

// Do what you want with secondStatus :)
```